# how to get rows that nth to mth columns are empty

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a csv file looks like this:

```
aaa,vvv,,,,
bbb,qqq,,,vvv,
ccc,www,iii,,,kkk
ddd,rrr,,,lll,
eee,ttt,ooo,sss,ggg,jjj
fff,yyy,ppp,,,
```

i want to get rows that nth to mth columns are empty (in this example:get rows that 3th to 4th are empty)

and then get output as follows

```
bbb,qqq,,,vvv,
ddd,rrr,,,lll,
```

Actually i want to get only rows that specific range columns are empty
for example with awk

```
awk -F, '$n-$m=="" {print}' file.csv
awk -F, '$3-$4=="" {print}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
awk -F, -v st=3 -v end=4 '{for(i=st;i<=end;i++){if($i){next;}}}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` solution by @Guru is probably much more portable than this, but using `grep` for **this specific** example:

```
egrep '^[a-z]*,[a-z]*,{3}[a-z]' csv 
bbb,qqq,,,vvv,
ddd,rrr,,,lll,
```

Where `csv` is this file:

```
cat csv
aaa,vvv,,,,
bbb,qqq,,,vvv,
ccc,www,iii,,,kkk
ddd,rrr,,,lll,
eee,ttt,ooo,sss,ggg,jjj
fff,yyy,ppp,,,
```

---

```
grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```